# Python package to find pre-defined keywords/tags in a file / url / string

Tags: python, keyword, stemming

Are there any python packages that can take a list of keywords / tags and match them up to a given string / file / url ?

Specifically using stemming and/or some other synonym way of matching.

i.e. my pre saved keywords:

`Ski,
Bike,
Climb`

my text:

`Skiing in the mountains is great`

Should get tagged with `Ski`

`Skiing and mountain biking is fun`

Should get tagged with `Ski` And `Bike`

And if I've got a synonyms file somewhere mapping `Bike` to `MTB`

`MTB is a great way to spend the day`

Should get tagged `Bike`

Comment: Sounds like a homework assignment - please add a "Homework" tag so that responders know to provide useful direction without copy&paste code.  As for stemming, are you looking for pointers to a library or you already have a stem-matching function?

Answer (score 0):

See [`Thesaurus`](http://packages.python.org/Whoosh/api/lang/wordnet.html#thesaurus) (you can also try different modules, such as [`synonym` module](http://www.cl.uni-heidelberg.de/~jakob/coli/LRApy/doc/synonym.html)).

Also you can test sentences for containing specific strings using `in`:

```
>>> 'Ski' in 'Skiing in the mountains is great'
True
>>> 'Bike' in 'Skiing in the mountains is great'
False
```

Comment: cheers for the thesaurus link - could be something Woosh could be utilised for I guess...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any package to do that but actually this is very simple with plain python. using re (regex) standard package. something like

```
import re
key_words =['ski','bike','climb'] 
input = "Skiing and mountain biking is fun"

input_words = input.split()#split on space
[word.lower() for word in input_words]
input_tags =[]
for word in input_words:
   for key in key_words:
      if re.search(key,word):
         input_tags.append(key)
```

Comment: There are multiple errors in your code: 1) words are not enclosed in quotes, 2) `input` is overwritten, 3) you can not split on empty string, 4) `str` has no `lowercase()` method (maybe `lower()`?), 5) instead of `if re.search(key,word)` you can as well use `if key in word` (you are not creating regular expression as `key`, btw.), 6) what your code does could be shortened a lot.

Comment: most are true - but this is fast pseudo code to answer for an obvious home work assignment. and showing how python work..